# Match & Replace String, utilising the original string in the replacement, in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to get to grips with the world of regular expressions in R.

I was wondering whether there was any simple way of combining the functionality of "grep" and "gsub"?

Specifically, I want to append some additional information to anything which matches a specific pattern.

For a generic example, lets say I have a character vector:

```
char_vec <- c("A","A B","123?")
```

Then lets say I want to append any letter within any element of `char_vec` with

```
append <- "_APPEND"
```

Such that the result would be:

```
[1] "A_APPEND"          "A_APPEND B_APPEND" "123?"
```

Clearly a `gsub` can replace the letters with `append`, but this does not keep the original expression (while `grep` would return the letters but not append!).

Thanks in advance for any / all help!

Comment: Doesn't `gsub` do what you need? `gsub("([[:alpha:]])", paste0("\\1", append), char_vec)`? See https://ideone.com/ERWJSg. What do you mean by *but this does not keep the original expression*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are not familiar with *backreferences* that you may use in the replacement patterns in `(g)sub`. Once you wrap a part of the pattern with a *capturing group*, you can later put this value back into the result of the replacement.

So, a mere `gsub` solution is possible:

```
char_vec <- c("A","A B","123?")
append <- "_APPEND"
gsub("([[:alpha:]])", paste0("\\1", append), char_vec)
## => [1] "A_APPEND"          "A_APPEND B_APPEND" "123?"
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/ERWJSg).

Here, `([[:alpha:]])` matches and *captures* into Group 1 any letter and `\1` in the replacement reinserts this value into the result.

Comment: perfect, many thanks! this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Definatly not as slick as @Wiktor Stribiżew but here is what i developed for another method.

```
char_vars <- c('a', 'b', 'a b', '123')

grep('[A-Za-z]', char_vars)
gregexpr('[A-Za-z]', char_vars)
matches = regmatches(char_vars,gregexpr('[A-Za-z]', char_vars))
for(i in 1:length(matches)) {

    for(found in matches[[i]]){

    char_vars[i] = sub(pattern = found, 
                       replacement = paste(found,  "_append", sep=""),
                       x=char_vars[i])

    }
}
```